# Small Difference in csv file size exported from sql server table using bcp utility and ssms?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, bcp

I am exporting a table into csv file from sql server using BCP utility and SSMS(export task).
I find that for a particular table i get the below file sizes.

```
Bcp file size:-4,030,064 kb
SSMS file size:- 4,030,213 kb
```

For smaller tables i am getting the same file size . Can you tell me the possible reasons for the small difference

Comment: Different encodings maybe?

Comment: I don't think the encodings are different

Comment: can you share your bcp command? Can you also share some details of how you went through the export wizard via SSMS? Rather than try to brainstorm a list of possible reasons, it would be much easier to troubleshoot with some info of how you did what you did. As an example, you could have any number of settings that do not match between the two. But if you configured both the same, there would be no difference.

Comment: last, how are you getting the size of the file?

Comment: I actually figured it out. The reason for the difference  in file size was because when I was using the bcp, the cells with empty  string was getting replaced with some  other character(I think newline but not sure). Where as with ssms the empty string was appearing as ,, . Would like to know if you have any other info?